# MySQL - auto increment not reseting

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I deleted the first 1000 rows in my table and i'm trying to set the auto_increment to 1 but its just setting the numbering automatically to the max ID value+1 .. how can i make it start numbering from 1 and continue to 1000?

ALTER TABLE `T` auto_increment = 1;

Comment: Short answer: You can not! Please read: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel so it's impossible to give a new row number 1 even if number 1 has been deleted in the past when we have a bigger values is that right ?

Comment: Not with AUTO_INCREMENT. As you already figured out, the AI value will be reset "to the max ID value+1". This is documented behavior. For InnoDB - see: [AUTO_INCREMENT Handling in InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html) "ALTER TABLE ... AUTO_INCREMENT = N can only change the auto-increment counter value to a value larger than the current maximum."

Comment: " so it's impossible to give a new row number 1 even if number 1 has been deleted in the past" - You can do it manually by setting the ID to a specific (non-duplicated) value in an INSERT or UPDATE statement. But then there would be no point in using the AOUTO_INCREMENT feature.

Comment: Why can't you put the data from your table into a new table, drop your original table, recreate your original table and then load the data back into that table?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reset auto-increment for INNODB table.

Thanks